# xcode referencing itmsTransporter at wrong path during upload

Tags: ios, xcode, itmstransporter

Xcode referencing itmsTransporter file at wrong path. My username changed and cant figure out how to correct the path where itmsTransporter is referenced at.

I've cleared all my previous archives, caches and build folder

I would like to change the path (my username) where itmsTransporter is being looked for. Image of error below. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Had the same exact problem. Simple solution. Navigate to ~/Users/[your new username]/.itmstransporter and then delete that directory. Next time you do an upload to itunesconnect that directory will be created again with proper references.

It is a hidden directory so you will need to make sure you are showing hidden files:

Open Terminal

Paste: defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES

Hit enter

Relaunch Finder